# How can I customize / override the "git clone" step in Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

On the install step, Travis CI clones the repo, which looks similar to this:

`git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/user/repo.git user/repo`

How can I customize / override this?

---

Background: I am using tag based deploys. The way Travis checks out tagged builds (`--branch=<tagname>`), the git repository is in a detached state without access to branches. However, for deployment I need to know on which branch I am. My solution is to do a "normal" clone and then switch to the tagged commit.

Answer (score 17):

You can clone the repository *again* in the install step. That way you clone the repository twice, but it seems to work.

```
# .travis.yml
install:
  - git clone https://github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG.git $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
  - cd $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
  - git checkout -qf $TRAVIS_COMMIT
```

Comment: Use `git clone git@github.com:${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}.git` if you're re-cloning a private repo with ssh,.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea because Travis config (`.travis.yml`) will be read from the previously checked out commit, as it's read before the install step, so before we checkout a different commit where the config file may have been changed.

Answer (score 12):

Per [the Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build) you can add the following to your `.travis.yml` to remove the [`--depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) flag:

```yaml
git:
  depth: false
```

As `--depth` implies `--single-branch`, removing this flag means that *all* branches will be checked out, which isn't the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I found that in order to get access to your whole repo you need the following:

```
install:
  - git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  - git fetch --unshallow --tags
```

This way you'll have access to remote branches and tags (e.g. can do checkout).

If you're on a tag but no longer want to be in a detached HEAD state you can create a new branch that points to the tag (according to [this discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Proper-way-to-checkout-a-tag-td5793287.html)):

```
install:
  - git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  - git fetch --unshallow --tags
  - git symbolic-ref --short HEAD || git checkout -b ${TRAVIS_BRANCH}-test $TRAVIS_BRANCH
```

Note: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` will fail if you're in a detached HEAD state.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not really that you are in a detached branch. It is that git does not allow you to fetch the tags: `git fetch --tags` will only fetch the branch spcified by `--branch` in the `git clone` command you gave.

I explain this in more details [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036486/1836144).

To solve you issue (checking out a specific tag) you can call a script that looks like this, after the repo is cloned:

```bash
    # Keep track of where Travis put us.
    # We are on a detached head, and we need to be able to go back to it.
    build_head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

    # fetch the tags
    git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    git fetch --tags

    # checkout the tagged commit
    git checkout -qf <your tag>

    # now do your stuff

    # go back to where we were at the beginning
    git checkout ${build_head}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this during your build to have access to origin tags / branches

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" 1>/dev/null
git fetch origin -q
```

After that you can run this command to find branches containing your commit

```
BRANCHES=`git branch -a --contains "$TRAVIS_TAG"`
```

---

I've created a script a loooong time ago to fetch the 'environment' branch where the tag was created for continuous deployment purpose.

It may inspire you: https://gist.github.com/rolebi/a0eb1f783b7f3a5f21a631c8da1582dc

Use it like that:

```
TARGET_ENV="`test $TRAVIS_TAG && bash scripts/get_branch_for_git_reference.sh $TRAVIS_TAG`"
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable [git clone](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#disabling-git-clone) and then clone the repository again in the install step. The repository will be cloned only once in this way. In this "*normal*" clone you will able to do what ever you want.

```
git:
  clone: false
install:
  - git clone https://github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG.git $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
  - cd $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just query the remote.  Add the following to `.travis.yml`:

```
env:
    global:
        # get all the branches referencing this commit
        - REAL_BRANCH=$(git ls-remote origin | sed -n "\|$TRAVIS_COMMIT\s\+refs/heads/|{s///p}")

        # or check if we are on a particular branch:
        - IS_RELEASE=$(git ls-remote origin | grep "$TRAVIS_COMMIT\s\+refs/heads/release$"
```

(I am surprised that the git gurus hadn’t come up with this one already)

Comment: But it only works, if the tag is on the latest commit on the branch you check. When the master branch is already ahead some commits, this gives you only `refs/tags/your-tag`.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the already existing shallow clone to a full clone. To do so execute *git fetch --unshallow* (available since git version 1.8.3) during the install step.

```
# .travis.yml
install:
  - git fetch --unshallow --tags
```

The *--tags* flag forces to fetch all tags even if they don't belong to the checked out branch. This is needed if your build also depends on tags from other branches.

Comment: that does not work because Travis clones the repositories with `--depth`, which implies `--single-branch`. `git fetch` will only fetch the branch that was cloned.