# Eslint files changed between branch and master in Travis CI

Tags: git, travis-ci, eslint

So basically when a branch is pushed I want to run a diff between the master branch and a target branch and then feed those files into eslint.

The command is:

`git diff --name-only master..$TRAVIS_BRANCH | grep -E '\.js$' | xargs npx eslint`

It works when I use it locally and replace $TRAVIS_BRANCH with my current working branch.

However, when I use this on travis ci, the build process only checks out the branch its testing against and not master. So it comes out with the error

```
$ git diff --name-only master..$TRAVIS_BRANCH | grep -E '\.js$' | xargs npx eslint
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..test-fail': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

How can I get travis CI to diff the files changed in a branch and run eslint only on those files?

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "lts/*"
  - "node"
  - "8"
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: lint
      script: git diff --name-only master..$TRAVIS_BRANCH | grep -E '\.js$' | xargs npx eslint
```

Comment: Why don't you just lint the whole thing in CI?

Comment: Not my question but the reason is because the test would fail. I basically want to enforce that new changes meet the standards but if there are problems already don't fail the build

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I customize / override the "git clone" step in Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580821/how-can-i-customize-override-the-git-clone-step-in-travis-ci)

Comment: yeah but I still don't know how to complete what I want. Maybe I can use the git sparse checkout thing. not sure

Comment: My guess is that, you are not pulling master, perhaps when you checkout you only get the current branch and mostlikly only the last revision of it.
Try replace master with origin/master. is it is the case

Answer (score 0):

To throw another answer into the mix that doesn't require python I came across [Fastlint](https://github.com/mixu/fastlint) which seems to do exactly this.

For example, run `eslint` on all `js` files in the `src` or `tests` directory changed compared to the `origin/master` branch.

```sh
fastlint --status --print0 --glob '{src,tests}/**/*.{js,jsx}' origin/master HEAD | xargs -0 eslint
```