# How to change directory of clone of the git clone step in Travis CI

Tags: github, travis-ci

in the first step, Travis CI clones the repo, using this

`git clone --branch=master https://github.com/user/repo.git user/repo`

how can I change it to

`git clone --branch=master https://github.com/user/repo.git custom_directory/repo`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580821/how-can-i-customize-override-the-git-clone-step-in-travis-ci).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I customize / override the "git clone" step in Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580821/how-can-i-customize-override-the-git-clone-step-in-travis-ci)